# How to pay somebody more than a million weekly?

Tags: fifa-15

In my career mode I got an email from Messi saying he wanted more money and his demands are a 1 million dollar weekly salary.

I can easily afford to pay that but I doesn't allow me to pay a million, only a 6 digit figure. How can I fix this?

Comment: What system is this for?

Comment: you might have to change your transfer budget. in the manager menu, usually under transfers, theres either a tab or slider that lets you allocate your current transfer budget and wage structure

Answer (score 1):

To pay more money go to your transfer budget and just change the sliders so that it allowes you to pay one million.